# How to integrate samples (1D np array) e.g. acceleration to speed

Tags: python

I have acceleration samples stored in numpy array and I want to compute sample by sample the speed, returned as an array from the acceleration data.
I had a look to various numpy /scipy functions but did not find a clue. Thanks;

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You should implement this simple formula yourself I think.

Comment: Can you add example i.e. input and desired output for that input?

Comment: Indeed I could implement this formula, but I was wondering whether there was a "standard" function available to this very classical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One function that will do what you're seeking is [numpy.trapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)

Scipy has many [options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) for this as well.  For a sample-by-sample integration, consider [scipy.integrate.cumtrapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html) as one option.

Comment: numpy.trapz will return one float value representing the integration over a range of evenly spaced samples of the input array. My data are sampled at 1Khz. So I presume I should / could use it by sliding a window over a set of samples, size to be tuned to the frequency of the expected result...

Comment: If what you want is the functional form have a look at scipy.integrate.cuntrapz

Comment: scipy.integrate.cumtrapz does the job. Thanks for suggestion !

Comment: An interesting blog post over data drifting when doing definite integration: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_avoid_data_drifting_when_integrating_acceleration_signal2